# Jacobian of the inverse of a matrix times a vector

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, vector-analysis, matrix-calculus, frechet-derivative

I come across this in my research. If we know $\frac{\partial \mathbf{Ab_1}}{\partial \mathbf x} = \mathbf M$, where $A$ is a matrix that depends on $\mathbf x$, and $ \mathbf b_1$ is a vector that does not depend on $\mathbf x$. Is it possible to get $\frac{\partial \mathbf{A^{-1} b_2}}{\partial \mathbf x}$? $\mathbf b_2$ does not depend on $\mathbf x$ either.

Comment: Could you clarify whether $x$ is a vector or a scalar? Also, is $M$ a matrix or a vector?

Comment: I guess $x$ is understood to be a matrix, including the case of a $1\times1$ matrix, i.e. a scalar.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible to get $\frac{\partial {A^{-1} b_2}}{\partial x}$ with the given hypothesis.  Here is an example illustrating what can happen:

Consider
$$
  A = A(x) = \pmatrix{\text{e}^x & 0 \cr 0 &  k\text{e}^x},
  $$
where $k$ is a nonzero constant.  Also let $b_1=\pmatrix{1\cr 0}$ and $b_2=\pmatrix{0\cr 1}$.  We then have that
$$
  M =
  \frac{\partial {Ab_1}}{\partial  x} =
  \frac{\partial}{\partial  x} \pmatrix{\text{e}^x\cr 0} =  \pmatrix{\text{e}^x\cr 0}.
  $$
On the other hand, the vector we are trying to "get", namely
$$
  \frac{\partial {A^{-1} b_2}}{\partial  x} =
  \frac{\partial}{\partial  x} \pmatrix{\text{e}^{-x} & 0 \cr 0 &  \text{e}^{-x}/k} \pmatrix{0\cr 1} =
  \frac{\partial}{\partial  x} \pmatrix{0\cr \text{e}^{-x}/k} =
  \pmatrix{0\cr -\text{e}^{-x}/k},
  $$
involves knowledge of the value of $k$, which is not given a priory.